# How do you debug a long ASCII character fprintf substitution statement?

Tags: c, printf

I have the following task:
I need to define a variable with a code template and then I need to compile it from within C. I wrote all this logic, but while manually inputting the characters replacements I messed up. You will know what I mean when you see my code below..

I have the following code:

```
fprintf(output_file,source_template,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,10,10,10,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,34,10,34,34,34,10,34,34,34,92,34);
```

...which is a mess. I messed up while inputting the ASCII characters and now it's a mess (some newlines are there where quotations marks should be and vice versa). How can I debug this better than just searching a text file and then comparing it to a text file? I tried doing that, I did fix a couple of issues, but new ones appeared.

Any guidance in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: `fputs(source_template, output_file);` will give you the format string.  This is one of the reasons, string literals are better for `*printf*` functions.  The first mistake could have been caught by your compiler/editor.

Comment: @Jason fputs like you wrote only prints out my variable which I already have defined... My code template is like the source but "encoded" so that C can compile the output written to file. Short example: `int main(){%cprintf(%chi%c);` would be the template and ASCII character decimal values of 10,34,34 would be required to display that.

Comment: Don't put ASCII codes numerically, use char literals. E.g. instead of `34`, write `'"'`

Comment: @Barmar that apparently doesn't minify code (double the amount of bytes) and does not help me debug it apparently :/

Comment: I didn't know about the minify requirement, I was just suggesting how to write your code to make it easier to debug in general.

Comment: Don't try to debug minified code. Write it in readable form, and use a tool to minify it.

Comment: @Barmar the thing is as you can see in the code above that I only need three characters - \n, " and \, which ASCII codes I already memorized. It doesn't make it per se easier to debug this mess, I can tell numbers apart too... But thanks for the tip, I wasn't aware C supports character literals.

Comment: Oh and I also forgot to mention - the program is also a quine, but that's a side-topic. In a quine you can't use character literals afaik.

Comment: And if someone happens to run your program in an EBCDIC locale, @SirMuffington?  Anyway, it's not about whether *you* know what the codes mean, at least today, but about your code being understandable to *others*.  Maybe even to future you.

Comment: It is not at all clear what your problem is.  If the code needs "debugging" then it implicitly contains a bug, but you have not stated what that bug us.  You say you "messed up" but did not state what the mistake was.  That would seem important if you want strategies to avoid similar errors.  It seems however that it is entirely pointless given the nature of the code, all elements of style and good practice rather go out of the window, when indulging in these academic coding novelties.

Comment: @Clifford I elaborated it. Yes, it is academic, but that's how you learn the novelties..

Comment: You missed my point. That is not however how you learn to write high quality code - it's just a game/puzzle, for entertainment.  Since you were in any case unaware of such fundamentals as character literals, it seems to be there are more useful things you could be learning.

Comment: It seems to me however that your question is more about avoiding typos than debugging - that is not quite the same thing. In this case you might write _legible_, _debuggable_ code to _generate_ and "minify" the unreadable/obfuscated code indirectly.  For example your code generator might have a "readable" string `"!!!!!!!\n\n\\!!!!"` (or whatever), and generate the corresponding list of comma separated ASCII codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the value of your `source_template` is supposed to have the form of a `printf` format string.  It's unusual to call that a "template", but ok.  And I don't particularly like [`f`]`printf` as a basis for a general-purpose templating system, but if you're committed to that then again, ok.

I take the problem to be how to figure out where in the lengthy list of similar arguments your mistakes are.  Being saddled with the templating system you present, you could consider introducing one or more intentionally bogus arguments to help you identify the locations in the argument list that correspond to the incorrect output.  For example, sub in one or more `'!'`, `'@'`, or `'$'` characters -- if your template is supposed to be for C code, then those should be pretty recognizable in the output.  Or use decimal digits -- these will not be as recognizable, but they can more directly convey positions in the argument list.

Comment: Discovered an additional great way to debug this using Python (the arr array is shortened due to brevity): `arr = [34,34,34,34,34,34,10,10]`
then:
`for index, value in enumerate(arr):
   print(f"'{index+1}'== {value}")`

Comment: When you have the indexes with the corresponding values you open up search in your IDE and search for `%[a-z]` and then search for corresponding values with the corresponding index.